# Open Source/Free disk imaging software

Tags: open-source, backup, image

I want to create an alternate restore option for my windows servers.  We do nightly backups, but I like to have alternate sources of backup data.  I'd like to install software on our servers that can create a disk image of the OS drive and store it on a network share.  The software needs to be able to create these images while the server is online and we would need to be able to use a boot disk to access the image and restore it in case of emergency.

So far, clonezilla sounded good, but I would need to shutdown the server and boot from clonzilla boot disk in order to create the image file.  So that's out.

I also tried Hasleo Disk Clone, but that doesn't create an image file, it just clones to another physical disk.

Then I tried disk2vhd, but that creates a hyper-v disk file for using it in a VM. I'm not sure if this is going to do what I need it to do.

I looked into Macrium Reflect, but they got rid of their free version.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You are going to have problems as it is difficult to backup files whcih are open. I think that VSS (Volume Shadow Service) is something that might help your search. Look for a solution which can use it.